# How to connect to Apache Hive Using SSL certificate from Java JDBC?

Tags: java, ssl, jdbc, hive

I am currently trying to make a simple connection between a Java class and an Apache Hive server.
However, I have not been able to do it due to a `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException` error.

This is the Java code that I am executing:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            String conStr = "jdbc:hive2://{{domain}}:{{port}}/default;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=C:/DBVisualization/gateway.jks;trustStorePassword=Password1;transportMode=http;httpPath=/gateway/default/hive";
            Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(conStr, "user", "password");
            if(con != null)
                System.out.println("Connected");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getAnonymousLogger().severe("There was an error while connecting to Hive");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2:{{url}}:{{port}}/default;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=C:/DBVisualization/cacerts;trustStorePassword=changeit;transportMode=http;httpPath=/gateway/default/hive: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://{{url}}:{{port}}/default;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=C:/DBVisualization/cacerts;trustStorePassword=changeit;transportMode=http;httpPath=/gateway/default/hive: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <IP> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []
```

As you can see I am pointing to the file where the certificate is, I used that same certificate for set up a DB visualizer connection and it worked. I am just do not know if for Java a different certificate is required. What am I doing wrong?